# Using real-world languages instead of made-up languages

Tags: languages

Let's say you're GMing a game for people who primarily speak English, and you want to have a non-human NPC say something in their native tongue, or a human NPC say something in a secret language. You could just make up some gobbledygook that doesn't mean anything, but what if you used a real-world language instead, like Latin or Italian or Spanish? It might be immersion-breaking if any of your players happens to speak one of those languages, but I think it might sound better than just making up a fake language.

Has anyone here ever used a real-world foreign language in place of a fantasy foreign language? Did you have any good or bad player feedback?

What about giving accents to your NPCs when they speak? Say if you have an NPC speak with a thick French accent, everyone will know it's a French accent, but France doesn't exist of course in the fantasy world.

Comment: This _seems_ to just be polling for opinion, not looking for a solution to an actual practical problem of any kind. What do you want to know, other than peoples' various experiences with it? Whether it's viable and whether it will break immersion / be a good experience?

Comment: Because RPG.se is a Q&A site for solving problems, one of the kinds of questions that are [explicitly off topic is](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) “I would like to participate in a discussion about _______.” You might be looking more for the kind of responses typical on a discussion forum, in which case we can [point you to a few that might suit this question well](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449), unlike this site.

Comment: This question is salvageable, and could be asked as "is using real-world languages in-game an effective technique for evoking verisimilitude".  Only ask this if that is, in fact, the question you want to ask, though.  There's nothing wrong with wanting a discussion, and if that's what you want I encourage you to pursue it, albeit elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

My Exalted groups usually assign a real-world language to each of the in-game languages, and it usually works out pretty well.  While no one in the group is truly bilingual, our interests are wide enough we know little smatterings and mannerisms from several languages, and it makes for quick characterization of minor NPCs, as well as allowing us to work our real-world memetic quirks into our own characters.  It also means, since we invariably assign Old Realm (the mostly forgotten dead language used primarily for magic, ghosts, and gods) Latin, that we can do some serious Harry Potter style language butchering if we have a sorcerer in the party.

The only major disagreement is whether Japanese should be used for Forest-tongue or Seatongue, usually.